# Why won't git-daemon serve my repositories?

Tags: git, git-daemon

I'm using git version 1.7.9 and while I've checked and double checked my configuration, I can't get the clones to work from the daemon. There's no indication of any error in /var/log/messages:

```
Feb 14 13:40:36 build git-daemon[9226]: Connection from 10.103.26.134:55331
Feb 14 13:40:36 build git-daemon[9226]: Extended attributes (22 bytes) exist <host=hostname.local>
Feb 14 13:40:36 build git-daemon[9226]: Request upload-pack for '/project.git'
Feb 14 13:40:36 build git-daemon[9220]: [9226] Disconnected (with error)
```

Nor on the client:

```
D:\git>git clone git://hostname.local/project.git project
Cloning into 'project'...
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Is there something obviously missing here?

```
git       9220     1  0 13:40 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-daemon --user=git --reuseaddr --verbose --detach --export-all --base-path=/home/git
```

I can clone and push to this repository just fine over SSH.

Comment: I think this question should be posted to [serverfault.com](http://www.serverfault.com) instead.

Comment: I thought about that, but seems to me the domain knowledge is far more likely to be on SO.

Comment: @Sorvahr: See the [faq]; questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are a core part of the scope of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ***git-daemon-export-ok*** file in the root of the repo?

See the [Git Community book](http://book.git-scm.com/index.html) for [Setting Up A Public Repository](http://book.git-scm.com/4_setting_up_a_public_repository.html)

Comment: It doesn't matter; he is using `--export-all`.